# Tags for social platforms

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [twitter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) (not to be confused with [twitter-bootstrap](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)). We also have questions about Whatsapp and Telegram, but those questions don't have specific tags yet.

In my opinion, we have 2 options:

1. We create tags for both Whatsapp and Telegram, to be used on questions involving code that does *vaguely gestures* something with those services. Whether they're bots, scrapers, handlers, etc., all tagged based on the service targeted. There are a decent number of questions per service already (a quick search yields 12 questions for Whatsapp, 31 for Telegram), so we'd have to coordinate the re-tagging effort (or flood the frontpage).
2. We outlaw such tags for not targeting a specific library. In which case it's a matter of time before we have a lot of tags that look a lot like each other with 1-3 questions each.

I'm fine with either and will volunteer to do the re-tagging. I'll post 2 answers to vote on, feel free to leave comments or post a third answer.

---

This question was prompted by [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/259360/52915), which created *too* specific tags.

Comment: I think "option 1" is best. If we start tagging everything related to a service now, if the tag grows too big we can filter by the existing tag when splitting off 'sub-tags'. Even if we never need to split a tag we'll have questions categorized for easier searching.

Comment: Someone created tags for Telegram 2 days ago. I know I approved at least 4 tag edits.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Are you talking about [tag:telegram-bot] and [tag:python-telegram-bot]? Because those tags are in the process of being removed.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about those tags.

Comment: When reading the title of this, I thought it was about "Which hashtags should we use on Twitter when we talk about Code Review Stack Exchange?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Option 1

Create new tags.

Answer (score -2):

#### Option 2

Outlaw the tags.